# Fiddler is interrupting my gmail chat connection

Tags: fiddler

When I have Fiddler running, my gmail chat connection is constantly interrupted and then I have to wait while it reconnects. Is there anything I can do about this problem?

Comment: This isn't really in scope for StackOverflow. Consider clicking Help > Fiddler Discussions and creating a new thread describing the exact steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Click the STREAM button in the Fiddler toolbar?

Comment: That made my gmail go even crazier. I got 407 response codes. Could it have something to do with the fact that I have decrypting enabled?

Comment: 407 response codes mean that you have an upstream authenticating proxy.